# I need to fix issues with parse.framework

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform

I haven't turned my app on for a while cause I do what I need in a separate project and then I implement it in the actual app. I'm working on it gives this

[image]

this has never happened before and yes I have the parse.framework it has been in since I started developing project so please help I dont know what this issue is I'm going to download an updated version of parse.framework and see if that works but please help

[image: i am linking it twice please help i have gone to those positions in the code but can not fix and i quit xcode and deleted the reference of the parse.framwork then replaced it and still this please help]

//// i EDITED the question

Comment: Quit the xcode, then open the xcode again and then remove the parse.framework reference and add it again, then clean and build it. It works for me..

Comment: thanks ill check and do that

Comment: i did that still got and issue though

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're accidentally linking the framework twice. Look through Xcode Log's Navigator and see if that's the case. Also, select the framework in the Project Navigator, open the File Inspector, and make sure that the framework is a member of the correct targets in your project.

Comment: You're only looking at the build errors, you probably need to examine all the messages.